# is there any way to use sleep(or delay) function in for loop in javascript

Tags: javascript, discord.js, delay, sleep

im new to javaScript and I'm writing a discord bot with discord .js
i want to make a delay in process.
setTimeout dont work because i want to delay in all of processes and but setTimeout just work for delay between 2 process.
and i dont know how to use promise-async and await cause im new.
is there anyway to do it? or how should i use async and await in discord bot making(i didnt write any function in bot codes)

and example from what i want :

```
for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++){
console.log(i);
sleep(5000);
```

}
output:

```
0
//sleep 5s
1
//sleep 5s
2
```

Comment: `setInterval`  or `setTimeout` can help you

Comment: `setInterval` might be what you're looking for.